# JqPlot Trim XAxis values

Tags: jqplot

How trim xaxis values in chart ?

[image: sample]

I am using http://www.jqplot.com/ plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
xaxis:{
  autoscale: true,
  formatString: "%.2f"
}
```

Let me know..